# Show that the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is the only unique left inverse of a non-square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, pseudoinverse

Let $A$ be an $N \times d$ matrix with $N > d$. Let $A^+$ be the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, i.e., $$A^+ = \left( A^T A \right)^{-1} A^T$$ We can see that $A^+$ is a left inverse of $A$ as $A^+A=I$. If $L$ is another $d \times N$ left inverse of $A$, show that $L = A^+ + E$ where $EA=0$. I honestly don't know where to start here, it isn't immediately obvious to me why this fact would be true.

Comment: Why is the number of rows uppercase and the number of columns lowercase?

Comment: Your formula is not correct as it seems to suggest that $(A^\intercal A)$ is invertible. The Moore-Penrose exists and is unique even when $(A^\intercal A)$ is not invertible. In fact $A^+=(A^* A)^+A^*$ (Here $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose matrix, to include matrices over $\mathbb{C}$). There are several ways to prove the existence of the MP-matrix. One geometric way is to use singular value decompositions. Any book on numerical analysis will likely have a treatment of this.